Login with any email (possibly out of workspace) and capture changes on sheet
I want to record data changes in a Google sheet by collecting the user's email and password. I am trying to make an Apps script that allows a user to log in with their email, then, once they are in, takes them to a Google sheet and captures the changes they make on a particular row.
I have a sheet and want to fill in 2 columns TimeLastUpdate and UserLastUpdate showing the time and email of the editor of each row.
My Apps script is not running as expected and is asking for permission to login but then does not take you to the sheet after.
Example
I am new to Apps Scripts and not very experienced using it, and I am struggling to get the workflow to execute once the app is deployed; I am not sure why this is the case. I have 2 files:

Code.gs
LoginPage.html

Code.gs
// Set up a global variable to store the email address obtained during sign-in
// onEdit.userEmail = '';

/**
 * The `onSignIn` function allows you to sign in.
 */
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
  
  // Store the email address in the global variable for later use in onEdit function
  onEdit.userEmail = profile.getEmail();
  
  var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
  console.log('ID Token: ' + id_token);
}

/**
 * The function `onEdit` updates "TimeLastUpdate" and "UserLastUpdate" columns in a Google Sheets document when a cell is edited.
 */
function onEdit(e) {
    if (!e || !e.range || !e.source) {
        console.error("The function must be triggered by an actual edit in the sheet.");
        return;
    }

    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var editedRow = e.range.getRow();
    var editedCol = e.range.getColumn();
    var numOfColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var targetColumnTime = numOfColumns - 1;
    var targetColumnUser = numOfColumns;

    if (editedRow > 1 && editedCol < targetColumnTime) {
        var now = new Date();
        sheet.getRange(editedRow, targetColumnTime).setValue(now);

        var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
        sheet.getRange(editedRow, targetColumnUser).setValue(user);
    }
}

function addDateColumns() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("SheetName");  // Adjust the sheet name
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  
  sheet.insertColumnsAfter(lastColumn, 60);
}

function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.load('auth2', function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'});
  });
}

function handleToken(idToken, email) {
  var url = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=' + idToken;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var responseJson = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  if (responseJson.email === email) {
    Logger.log("Token is valid and email verified: " + email);
  } else {
    Logger.log("Invalid token or email mismatch.");
  }
}

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('LoginPage')
    .evaluate()
    .setTitle('Login with Google')
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}


LoginPage.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login with Google</title>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <script>
      gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        // Initialize the Google auth API with your actual Client ID
        gapi.auth2.init({
          client_id: '49931792205-8h4ep2b4j25k7rvn66fpahevr9p4ts4r.apps.googleusercontent.com' 
        }).then(function(auth2) {
          // Check if the user is already signed in
          if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
            var googleUser = auth2.currentUser.get();
            onSignIn(googleUser); // Automatically sign in the user
          }
        });
      });
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        var email = 'tom@google.com';
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

        // Assign the email variable an id of "userEmail"
        document.getElementById("userEmail").textContent = email;
        
        // Send the token to the server using google.script.run
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
            console.log("Login successful: " + response);
            // Redirect the user to the Google Sheet URL
            google.script.run.redirectToGoogleSheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ged7yFTRFl6GmcuzNJkrwdikEdHSsx28VnZZAbZFXn8/edit?pli=1#gid=716652807');
        }).withFailureHandler(function(error) {
            console.error("Login failed: " + error);
        }).handleToken(id_token, email);
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>    
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
    <p>Hello World! The user email is: <span id="userEmail"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login with Google</title>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <script>
      gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        gapi.auth2.init({
          client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
        }).then(function(auth2) {
          if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
            var googleUser = auth2.currentUser.get();
            onSignIn(googleUser);
          }
        });
      });
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        var email = profile.getEmail();
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

        document.getElementById("userEmail").textContent = email;
        
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
            console.log("Login successful: " + response);
        }).withFailureHandler(function(error) {
            console.error("Login failed: " + error);
        }).handleToken(id_token, email);
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
    <p>Hello World! The user email is: <span id="userEmail"></span></p>
</body>
</html>


Reference:

How to know who and when edited my Google Sheet


The question needs less code. Please add a [mcve]. Also it needs more focus.

onEdit is a reserved function name for simple triggers. This kind of trigger has limitations, like a shorter maximum execution time limit. Check out https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Ok @Wicket, I hear you and will do so.

Another thing, gapi was not declared on the server-side code (Code.gs). When adding the "mcve", don't forget to add the textual error message or relevant logs.
